# typedef using template arguments not working with g++

Tags: c++, c++11

The following code compiled under MVCC but not g++, and i'm not sure why.

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
public:
  template <typename C>
  class B
  {
  public:
    C* cptr;
  };

  typedef typename A<T>::B<T> Ttype;
};

int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
  A<int>::Ttype d;
  d.cptr = 0;
}
```

with g++, you get

```
error: 'typename A<T>::B name template<class T> template<class C> class A<T>::B', which is not a type
```

I am compiling with -std=c++11

Comment: clang compiles it, must be a bug in GCC

Comment: Which version of gcc? `gcc --version`

Comment: Simply using `typedef B<T> Ttype;` solves the issue.

Comment: @Guilherme: And again that didn't work for me in GCC 4.8.1. (It should have done)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I tested both mine and 0x499602D2's solution with GCC 4.8.1 (MinGW). Both worked.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal gcc-4.7.2

Comment: Looks like the issue is that the typename is "Not needed" (and thus is considered an error) in g++, but "needed" in mvcc and thus is not an error. Using `typedef B<T>` indeed works in both.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal: Oh, yes, sorry `template` works.

Comment: Which version of VC are you using? According to this article, 2010 would compile without disambiguating the template, but 2012 would not as it follows the standard. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dx2zs2ee.aspx

Comment: @polkadotcadaver Yup, its VC2010, which is the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the gcc error message, the problem is you claim `A<T>::B` is a type but it isn't: it a class template. Both [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org) and [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) are happy with

```
typedef A<T>::B<T> Ttype;
```

i.e., remove the `typename`. In the given context it wouldn't be possible to specialize `B` to be something different than what it obviously is anyway.

The `using`-alias does just the same with a different syntax:

```
using Ttype = A<T>::B<T>;
```

The notation using an extra `template` keyword first states that `B` is actually a `template` and then, in combination with the `typename` that the instantiation `B<T>` is a type:

```
typedef typename A<T>::template B<T> Ttype;
```

or

```
using Ttype = typename A<T>::template B<T>;
```

Since the class template `B` is local anyway, the qualification isn't really needed in this context, i.e.

```
typedef B<T> Ttype;
```

and

```
using Ttype = B<T>;
```

do work as well.

Comment: @0x499602D2 LightnessRacesinOrbit's answer is using type aliasing, different approach.

Comment: And, of course, `typedef B<T> Ttype;` is accepted as well by g++4.8 and clang++3.4

Answer (score 6):

I think this is a bug with MVCC. This doesn't compile because you  need to use `template` to disambiguate `B` as a template:

```
typedef typename A<T>::template B<T> Ttype;
```

Comment: @uk4321 It compiled for me.

Comment: Good answer. MVCC (version 16.00.40219.01) doesn't accept this, just to clarify the MVCC bug.

Comment: I think the `template` is *not* required here, since `B<T>` is a member of the current instantiation. See [temp.names]/4 (for the `template` keyword) and [temp.dep.type]/4 (for *member of the current instantiation*).

Answer (score 5):

Looks like a bug to me.

The following works in GCC 4.8.1:

```
using Ttype = A<T>::B<T>;
```